# Does Hibernate support referencing Entities by ids instead of direct references?

Tags: c#, java, hibernate, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I was reading [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) by Vaughn Vernon  and in the chapter about aggregates the following structure is shown:

[image]

This structure can be mapping easily using Hibernate/NHibernate as the each entity references the aggregate root by reference.

However, he decides to refactor the design to this:

[image]

Now all entities reference the root using the `ProductId` value object instead.

How can one model this using Hibernate/NHibernate?

The explanation for the diagrams can be found here [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)

Comment: Not sure why to do so but a simple `Map(x => x.ProductId)` or `Component(x => x.ProductId, c => c.Map(...))` would suffice no?

Comment: @Firo I added a link for the explanation for the diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

In hbms of BacklogItem, Rlease, Sprint

```
<component name="productId">
    <property name="value" column="product_id"/>
</component>
```

Or in JPA style

```
@Embedded
@OverrideAttributes....
private ProductId productId
```

In this case, the BacklogItem doesn't need to lazyload the Product, so a simple identifier is enough. Just treat them as hibernate components.

Comment: NHibernate is smart enough to not lazy load a Product if all you want is the Id of the referenced ProductObject. I guess Hibernate does so too?

Comment: @Firo The solution is driven by ddd principles, not by persistence infrastructure. So only ProductId alone is needed even if hibernate supports.

Answer (score 0):

with (Fluent-)NHibernate it would look like

```
Component(x => x.ProductId, c => c.Map(pid => pid.Value, "product_id"));
```